# No route matches [POST] "/admin/order/1/images/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm getting an error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/admin/order/1/images/new"
```

These are my **associations**

```
Order has many :images
Image belongs_to :order
```

**schema**

```
create_table "images", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "order_id"
  t.string  "image_url"
end
```

**form**

```
<%= form_tag new_admin_order_image_path(@order.id), enctype: 'multipart/form-data' do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :image  %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Upload image' %>
<% end %>
```

**routes**

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :orders, only: [:edit, :index, :show, :update] do
    resources :images
  end
end
```

**controller**

```
class Admin::ImagesController < AdminController
  def new
    @image =Image.new(
      image_url: 'nvm.jpg'
    )

    if @image.save
      redirect_to :back, success: 'File successfully uploaded'
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = 'There was an error'
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting `new_admin_order_image_path` with `POST` method. where as `new_admin_order_image_path` is `GET` route.

So you need to change the route to `admin_order_images_path(@order.id)` in your form which will hit `Images#create` action

```
<%= form_tag admin_order_images_path(@order.id), enctype: 'multipart/form-data' do %>
```

create a `create` method in your controller

```
class Admin::ImagesController < AdminController
  def new
    @image =Image.new
  end

  def create
    @image =Image.new(
      image_url: 'nvm.jpg'
    )

    if @image.save
      redirect_to :back, success: 'File successfully uploaded'
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = 'There was an error'
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two routes related to creating new records, which could be seen by running `rake routes`:

```
 order_images     POST  /admin/orders/:order_id/images(.:format)      images#create
 new_order_images GET   /admin/orders/:order_id/images/new(.:format)  images#new
```

`images#new` is a `GET` request, which is used for *loading* the form.

`images#create` is a `POST` request, which is used to *submit* the form.

To fix your code, change: `new_admin_order_images_path` to `admin_order_images_path`.

You also need to define a `create` action in the Controller, and perform the save action in there; *not* in the `new` action. Something along the lines of:

```
class Admin::ImagesController < AdminController
  def new
    @image = order.find_by(params[:order_id]).images.new(
      image_url: 'nvm.jpg'
    )
   end

  def create
    if @image.save
      redirect_to :back, success: 'File successfully uploaded'
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = 'There was an error'
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a create action to you 'ImageController' and put image create logic there.Currently you have only new action and you are saving the image there,which you can actually place in the create action.

```
  def create
   @image =  Image.new({image_url: "image.png"})

   if @image.save 
     redirect_to root_url
   else 
     flash.now[:notice] = 'There was an error'
     render :new
  end
```

You have make slight change in the url from new_admin_order_image_path to admin_order_images(@order).

```
 <%= form_tag admin_order_images(@order), enctype: 'multipart/form-data' do %>
   <%= file_field_tag :image  %>
   <%= submit_tag 'Upload image' %>
<% end %
```